# React strange behavior when calling as function and when calling as component, focus on input disapears after typing one character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, components, focus

I am react beginner and I would like to create 2 inputs for first and last name.

When i call `<Item/>` the focus on input disappears after typing one character, but when i call `{Item()}` everything works fine as expected. It looks like some strange behavior to me and my question is why? Any ideas?

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Item() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("John");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("Rambo");

  function HandleFirstNameChange(event) {
    setFirstName(event.target.value);
  }

  function HandleLastNameChange(event) {
    setLastName(event.target.value);
  }

  // display
  function Display(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        {firstName}, {lastName}
      </div>
    );
  }

  // edit
  function Edit(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={firstName}
            onChange={HandleFirstNameChange}
          />
          <input type="text" value={lastName} onChange={HandleLastNameChange} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Display />

      {/* here after typing one character focus of input disappears */}
      <Edit />

      {/* here everything works fine as expected */}
      {Edit()}

      {/* whyyyy?? */}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Item />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're defining your components within your `Item` component, so they get recreated each re-render (so the previous `<Edit />` component is different to the current `<Edit />` component). You should move your components (such as `Edit`) outside of your `Item` component, and use props to pass the dependent items down into it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are defining the Edit component inside the Item component and so on every render, Edit function will be defined again and because of that react will try and replace it in the DOM tree on every render.

When you are calling the function, you are not actually using the Edit function as a React component. The below code will work just fine.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// display
function Display(props) {
  const { firstName, lastName } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {firstName}, {lastName}
    </div>
  );
}

// edit
function Edit(props) {
  const {
    firstName,
    HandleFirstNameChange,
    lastName,
    HandleLastNameChange
  } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" value={firstName} onChange={HandleFirstNameChange} />
        <input type="text" value={lastName} onChange={HandleLastNameChange} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

function Item() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("John");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("Rambo");

  function HandleFirstNameChange(event) {
    setFirstName(event.target.value);
  }

  function HandleLastNameChange(event) {
    setLastName(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Display firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} />

      {/* here after typing one character focus of input disappears */}
      <Edit
        firstName={firstName}
        lastName={lastName}
        HandleFirstNameChange={HandleFirstNameChange}
        HandleLastNameChange={HandleLastNameChange}
      />

    </div>
  );
}

export default Item;
```